# Loop through a dictionary with multiple values of a custom class?

Tags: python

I have following code:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm


class European_Option:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.S = kwargs.get("S")
        self.X = params.get("X")
        self.sigma = params.get("sigma")
        self.r = params.get("r")
        self.T = params.get("T")
        self.d1 = (np.log(self.S / self.X) + (self.r + 0.5 * self.sigma ** 2) * (self.T)) / (
            self.sigma * np.sqrt(self.T)
        )
        self.d2 = (np.log(self.S / self.X) + (self.r - 0.5 * self.sigma ** 2) * (self.T)) / (
            self.sigma * np.sqrt(self.T)
        )

    def call(self):
        C = norm.cdf(self.d1) * self.S - norm.cdf(self.d2) * self.X * np.exp(-self.r * self.T)
        return C

    def put(self):
        P = -norm.cdf(-self.d1) * self.S + norm.cdf(-self.d2) * self.X * np.exp(-self.r * self.T)
        return P


params = {"S": 50, "X": 100, "sigma": 0.25, "T": 1, "r": 0.05}
print(European_Option(**params).call())
```

Now I want to loop over a dictionary with multiple values and calling my `European_Option.call()` method.

```
params2={"S":[50,100], "X":[100,200],"sigma":0.25,"T":1,"r":0.05}
print(European_Option(**params2).call())
```

Obviously, this will result in an error. How can I do that?

Comment: What obvious error are you getting?

Comment: Following error:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'int' --> he gets a list of values for X and S but it should only be a single value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
params2={"S":np.array([50,100]), "X":np.array([100,200]),"sigma":0.25,"T":1,"r":0.05}
print(European_Option(**params2).call())
```

You cannot divide regular python `list` by scalar (you can multiply, yet it means something else then).

Comment: That solves the type problem, but doesn't it introduce a semantic problem, I wonder? I.e. make wrong calculations. It is different compared to the itertools.product solution in terms of produced numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools%20product#itertools.product) to combine all the *S* values with all the *X* values, for instance:

```py
s_list = [50, 100]
x_list = [100, 200]

for s, x in itertools.product(s_list, x_list):
    params = {"S": s, "X": x, "sigma": 0.25, "T": 1, "r": 0.05}
    print(European_Option(**params).call())
```

output:

```
0.027352509369436673
1.922075153371893e-07
12.335998930368717
0.054705018738873346
```